# Autofill textfield with custom text after selected a stat from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need some help for this script. It's a script I got from other place and I would like to add a function to it but I really got stuck. This is the script:

```
          <select name="order_status_id">
            <?php foreach ($order_statuses as $order_statuses) { ?>
            <?php if ($order_statuses['order_status_id'] == $order_status_id) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $order_statuses['order_status_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $order_statuses['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $order_statuses['order_status_id']; ?>"><?php echo $order_statuses['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry_notify; ?></td>
        <td><input name="notify" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry_comment; ?></td>
        <td><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="8" style="width: 99%"></textarea>
```

I would like to fill the textfield automatically after I selected one name from the dropdown menu. 
for example in the **dropdown listbox** I selected a status **"Processing"** then the **textfield** below will automatically fill with **"We are now processing your request. Please wait for X days and we would inform you shortly."**

So when I selected another status "canceled" , the textfield will change it's content with "We have cancelled your request." and so on..

Please tell me if my description wasn't clear enough. Thank you so much beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a javascript function that will do what you need in the `onchange` event of your select box like this:

```
<select id="order_status_id" name="order_status_id" onchange="updateTextBox()">
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="40" rows="8" style="width: 99%"></textarea>
```

Also I added `id` values for both elements so we can easily select them with `getElementById`

This event would fire each time you change the selection. You then would implement a simple javascript function `updateTextBox()` that will update the textbox for you:

```
function updateTextBox() {
    var orderStatusSelect = document.getElementById("order_status_id");
    var status = orderStatusSelect.options[orderStatusSelect.selectedIndex].text;
    var myTextBox = document.getElementById("comment");

    if(status == "Processing") {
        //set the value of the text box
        myTextBox.value = "We are now processing your request. Please wait for X days and we would inform you shortly." ;
    } else if(status == "Cancelled") {
        myTextBox.value = "We have cancelled your request!";
    } else if(status == "OtherStatus") {
        myTextBox.value = "another message goes here!";
    }
    //and so on for all different options
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEH8L/3/) for a running example.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried it out but still nothing comes out in the textfield.. anything else could be the problem?

Comment: Fixed it so it works in a jsFiddle, take a look and see if it helps